# Repeater within a repeater options page – grab data from first repeater loop

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

The image and code below should sumarise

[image]

Essentially I want the document link to display on the post object pages within the sub-repeater field. I've managed to get the code working without a sub-repeater (post object only) but that means the document can only be displayed on one page... which isn't ideal as the client wants the documents accessible on multiple pages - as well as being more user friendly in regards to organising documents (they add and remove documents frequently)

```
<?php if ( have_rows('documents2', 'option') ) :  
 $currentPageID = $post->ID;
 $countCheck = 0;

 while ( have_rows('documents2', 'option') ) : the_row(); 

if ( have_rows('document_pages') ) : 

  while ( have_rows('document_pages') ) : the_row(); 

    $post_object = get_sub_field('document_page');

    if ($post_object->ID == $currentPageID) {
      $countCheck++;
    }

       endwhile;   

       endif; 

  endwhile;
```

This is working properly - it's counting both instances of homepage.

```
if($countCheck > 0): 
  ?>

  <div class="documents">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <h2 class="text-center">Documents</h2>
          <?php 
          $documentCategories = array();

          while ( have_rows('documents2', 'option') ) : the_row();

            if ( have_rows('document_pages') ) :  

              while ( have_rows('document_pages') ) : the_row(); 
              $post_object = get_sub_field('document_page');

                if ($post_object->ID == $currentPageID) {
```

This is where the code begins to falter - I want to go back to the parent repeater and display the respective category on the page - but as it's a parent loop within a parent loop it loops infinitely (i believe... or at least the page times out with a 501 error!)

```
      if ( have_rows('documents2', 'option') ) :  

                    while ( have_rows('documents2', 'option') ) : the_row(); 
                    $terms = get_sub_field('document_category2');

                      if( $terms ): 

                        foreach( $terms as $term ):
                        $tag = $term->name;


                          echo $tag;

                        endforeach;

                      endif;

                    endwhile;

                  endif;

                } 

              endwhile;

            endif;

          endwhile;

          ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

I've tried a break and return but it means losing the $post_object data... any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try adding reset_rows( true ); after the first loop?

Comment: sadly wherever i put reset_rows there is no change...